# Flag questions for migration to math or cs

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When flagging a question on SO as offtopic and suggesting migration, math and cs are not on the list of site where it can be moved to (there are only meta, superuser, tex, dba and sharepoint). I sometimes stumble over questions that appear in CS context and are mostly math, so they should belong to one of these sites. Are these cases so seldom that they do not appear on the lists of valid suggested migrations or are there other reasons? If this is not the case, I would suggest adding these alternatives.

Comment: or just one option, where we can give the link to the website that we want it to get migrated.

Comment: select the other option and written as " This question belongs to *** this site" and put close vote on it.

Comment: @Avinash Raj That's what I have done in these cases up to now.

Comment: Ok, after reading the other posts I see that using the "other" flag seems to be totally approriate. I just wasn't aware that offtopic questions regarding tex are more frequent than cs. I would have guessed that it's the other way around.

Comment: I don't think its a duplicate to "More options when flagging for migration", because it is more specific. But I agree it is surely related.